# Navigatng between html pages is not working in Flask

Tags: html, flask

Firstly I am very new to Flask. I created a templates folder and moved all the html files there. Now i created a static folder and moved all my js files, images and css files there. Now in my index.html, I have navigation links as follows,

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse tm-nav" id="navbar-nav">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="/services.html">Services</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="/about.html">About</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>                            
                        </div>
```

Now in my app.py for page navigation I am doing something like below. When I open  http://127.0.0.1:5000/  in browser, I can only see the index.html. But when I click on services or about it says "404 Not found. The requested URL was not found on the server." Please help what am I doing wrong.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/services")
def services():
    return render_template('services.html')

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
```

I see the following in the command prompt.

[image: problem navigating]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about routing in flask [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#routing)

You need to call the function attached to the URL with `url_for` or you can also put the direct URL there. For example `/services`.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse tm-nav" id="navbar-nav">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="{{url_for('services')}}">Services</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="{{url_for('about')}}">About</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>                            
                        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you I did that for all the css files but I didin't replace the links. Should I say src="{{ url_for('templates',filename='servies.html')}}" or href="{{url_for('services')}}"